# Tomcat5 "Null component" and "HTTP Status 404 - Servlet jsp is not available"

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat, web-applications

I need to move my application from tomcat6 to tomcat5. The application is deployed, but I can't access it with web browser.

And now step by step:

1) Folders "work/Catalina/localhost/", "conf/Catalina/localhost/" and "webapps/" are free from files connected with my project.

2) Using tomcat-maven plugin I deploy my application and it appears in application list on Web Application Manager's page.

3) When opening any page of my application I get the following error, displayed in the web browser window:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet VoucherManager is not available

type Status report

message Servlet VoucherManager is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet VoucherManager is not available) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/5.5.30
```

And going to "catalina..log" I see:

```
04.08.2010 12:30:10 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive VoucherManager.war
04.08.2010 12:30:11 org.apache.commons.modeler.Registry registerComponent
SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=JspMonitor,name=jsp,WebModule=//localhost/VoucherManager,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
```

My "context.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Loader
    loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It started working after deleting *context.xml* that is mentioned above.